# How to create a Trigger (Mysql )

Tags: mysql, triggers

i'm new to SQL so i ask your help. In my DB i have a table called "table" with some field as "name", "lat", "lng", "error". Now i want to check for each update event the error field of this table and delete the rows which have error value > 3. I think that a Trigger can be used for this role, and i wrote the follow code:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trigger_update`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `table`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        DELETE FROM `table` WHERE error > 3;

    END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

but nothing happens when i update table and the error field of a row is higher than 3.
I'm sorry for my english and for my mistakes in code. Thanks to eveybody.

UPDATE 
@RiggsFolly, you say to modify in this way the code ? I take a sintax error.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trigger_update`;
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `table`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        DELETE FROM `table` WHERE error > 3;

    END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

@Jmons i know this, the name "table" is only as example, in DB the table has a different name, thanks.
I have insert wrong tags, i'm sorry.

Comment: Remove this line `DELIMITER //`

Comment: Amend `END` to `END;$$`

Comment: Hi, slightly unrelated, can I suggest that you don't use table-names or field names which are keywords. It can lead to confusion later (especially if you type some not-quite-perfect sql): the full keyword list is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx (its just good practice for readability and code maintainability).

Comment: Please note that SQL Server (owned by Microsoft) and MySQL (currently owned by Oracle) are entirely different programs with entirely different trigger syntax.

Comment: what DB are you using  ? The code does not looks like sql server

Comment: i' ve made a mistake with Tags, i'm sorry.

Comment: Put the line `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_update;` before the first `delimiter`. Now your trigger would be correctly created. Unfortunately, it will not work. With MySQL, it is not possible in a trigger to update (that includes deletes and inserts) the same table that the trigger is on, so you will get an error. You should try it though, it is good to see it once and not just believe me. What you can believe is that there is no way around that (no, the trick you think of right now will not work), so you have to find a different place to delete the rows you don't want to have (e.g. a query).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do a delete statement on the same table as the trigger. 
Here are a good explanation : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27094683/4505007